# How to convert rails active resource object to hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

Let's say I have some active resource object fetched as the following:

```
x = Resource.find(some_id)
```

And x in the remote server has some field `h` as a complex nested hashes which is represented here as nested active resource objects, but then accessing it is a tedious task, so is it possible to convert `h` to hash? I can just make another call Resource.get(some_id) and the result will be one big hash, but this is risky as the resource -theoretically- may have changed between subsequent calls, so is there a way to convert active resource object to hash ?

**Edit**

For more clarification, Suppose that some invoice record r[id=some_id] has attribute `extras`, which is a hash with the value: `{:x=>1, :y=>2, :z=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}`

Then when fetching this record through active resource, we get the following result for extras field, -extracted from the response-:

```
   "extras"=>
    #<App::Invoice::Extras:0x00000008202cb0
     @attributes=
      {"x"=>1,
       "y"=>2,
       "z"=>
        #<App::Invoice::Extras::Z:0x00000008201978
         @attributes={"a"=>1, "b"=>2},
         @persisted=true,
         @prefix_options={}>},
     @persisted=true,
     @prefix_options={}>,
```

Then how to convert this extras field to a ruby hash ?

Comment: can you give a more elaborate example of what you may be wanting to do?

Comment: can you try `Resource.find(some_id).as_json`

Comment: @ArupRakshit well as_json only converted the first level of the response to hash, so instead of x.extras, we have now x["extras"], but the value of extras is the same old active resource object. However JSON.parse(x._to_json) did the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse(x.to_json)` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x = Resource.find(some_id)
hash = OpenStruct.new(x).to_h
```

or

```
hash = OpenStruct.new(x.attributes).to_h
```